# Create New Frames Programmatically

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame, flashdevelop

I was building an beginner application with Flashdevelop, when I met the following problem.

I would like to create a MovieClip type Table.as class:

```
public class Table extends MovieClip { ... }
```

which should contain two frames: the first should be a red rectangle, the second a blue one. So created two sprites for both of the rectangles:

```
var table:Sprite = new Sprite();
table.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
table.graphics.drawRect(this.xCoord, this.yCoord, 150, 50);
addChild(table);

var table2:Sprite = new Sprite();
table2.graphics.beginFill(0x0000ff);
table2.graphics.drawRect(this.xCoord + 200, this.yCoord + 100, 150, 50);
addChild(table2);
```

What should I do to get the `table` and `table2` variables on different frames? So to receive to the `trace(totalFrames)` 2 as answer?

Comment: Sprite don't have timeline. I guess with AS3 it is not possible to add `KeyFrames` as you add in Flash IDE timeline. Instead use Array to store those `MovieClips` and treat it as if it would be frames.

Comment: Yes, this was the answer I was a little bit afraid of - that only Adobe implements the frameflow, Flashdevelop does not support it, just have to find another solution - such as the one you suggested with arrays. Thank you anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

MovieClips and Sprites that are generated outside of Flash IDE function more or less identically. Only a MovieClip created inside Flash IDE can have multiple frames, and you can't add or remove frames at run time.
However, you can create a simple class to switch between your two tables fairly quickly

```
public class Switcher():void {
  function showTable1():void { table1.visible = true; table2.visible = false; };
  function showTable2():void { table1.visible  = false; table2.visible = true; };


}

var switch:Switcher = new Switcher();
switch.showTable1();
```

Comment: Using .alpha is a terrible advice. Setting .visible would be a valid solution.